# Нужна ли запятая между словами лифт грузоподъемностью... скоростью подъема

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая между словами лифт грузоподъемностью... скоростью подъема....

Answer (score 0):

Да, запятая ставится на основании нескольких несогласованных определений, автоматически являющихся однородными.

Comment: А зачем было объявлять тревогу? По-моему, суть вопроса вполне понятна.